# I want my text box to allow vb script code as text without getting an error in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a TextBox and I want to allow VB syntax, but when I run the site and try to save the VB code to the database, I am getting an error. I believe the error has something to do with the VB code.

I have put the `httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"` setting in my web.config, and I've added `validateRequest="false"` in the directive at the top of the page, but it didn't resolve the issue.

How can I solve this problem?

```
Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
Dim myCommand As SqlCommand 
Dim ra As Integer 
myConnection = New SqlConnection("Integrated Security=True") 
myConnection.Open() 
myCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [tblScripts] ([Script],[Script_Name]) VALUES ('" & txtScript.Text & "','" & txtName.Text & "'", myConnection) 
ra = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 
myConnection.Close() –
```

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near ' & XID & '.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'any'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Then'.
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'btnNewIssue'. Its as if its debugging through the code in the text box

Comment: Can you post the code that handles the text entered, i.e. after the text is entered if some button is clicked, the click event handler and the downstream Db code that runs

Comment: Can you post the stack trace and any relevant code?

Comment: Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
        Dim myCommand As SqlCommand
        Dim ra As Integer

        myConnection = New SqlConnection("Integrated Security=True")
        myConnection.Open()
        myCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [tblScripts] ([Script],[Script_Name]) VALUES ('" & txtScript.Text & "','" & txtName.Text & "'", myConnection)
        ra = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myConnection.Close()

Comment: cant put in the datasource or database online sorry (they are normally in before the "integrated security")

Comment: Hello [Bobby Tables](https://www.xkcd.com/327/).
That's your problem, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a parametrized query. 
Your query is now building on the fly, so everything around "" is taking literal, and is taking as part as the original query.

You should pass parameters to it to avoid it (and also avoid SQL injections and so on)...